# What does the ! in { addressCity :: !Text } mean?

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Text (Text)

data Address = Address
  { addressCity :: !Text }
```

What is the purpose of the `!`?

Based on: https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/lens/.

Comment: It's a strictness annotation, which will force that field to be evaluated immediatey when the address constructor is applied.

Comment: @chi Please don't post answers as comments. Can you copy your comment into an answer and add a few details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a strictness annotation. Data constructor fields with an `!` will be strictly evaluated.

Another place you often see this is when using the `BangPatterns` language extension. You can cause the function to strictly evaluate by annotating the parameter with an `!` e.g.

```
foo :: Num a => a -> b
foo !a = ((++) a 1)
```

Comment: Strictness annotations on `data` fields don’t require `BangPatterns`. They’re a language feature of Haskell 98. See [Haskell 98 Report §4.2.1 Strictness Flags](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html). `BangPatterns` only apply to patterns, typically variables, like `f !x = …` or `g (!x, !y) = …`.